# Java code for downloading a zipped folder

Tags: java

I need to download a zipped folder of map data from the url in this python code below. This Python code works perfectly, but as the title suggests, I have to write the program in Java and its not as easy as in python.

```
   import requests 


def download_url(url, save_path, chunk_size=128):
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(save_path, 'wb') as fd:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
            fd.write(chunk)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    download_url("https://vaarweginformatie.nl/fdd/main/wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.Application/downloadfileResource?fileId=2692343839", "/home/NAME/Documents/Python/file.zip")
```

As you can see, the URL doesn't end in .zip, and some of the code I could find would have this as a requirement.

I tried the top ~5 Stackoverflow posts about this issue and none of them seem to work. They all end up giving me the same error.

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Java seems to ask for a SSL certificate, while python does not. I would rather not add the SSL certificate, because it is not easily applicable in the end use of this program.

The question still boils down to: How do I download a zipped folder from a URL with Java?

Comment: try removing the `s` from `https` from the URL, use this url instead `http://vaarweginformatie.nl/fdd/main/wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.Application/downloadfileResource?fileId=2692343839` note: this approach may be unsecured

Comment: You have no option but to download the cer and add to the trust store.  I understand your reluctance, but the fact of the matter is the JVM is suppose to do this automatically anyway.  There is no other way

Comment: No ChrisMaggiulli, removing the s in the https link does indeed work perfectly. Thanks @AvielNiego ! The program is only for a PoC, so security is not a priority.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the S from https at the start of the link solved this issue. Note: this approach may be unsecured. Answer provided by @AvielNiego